# how to display random xml layouts in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

my app has a bunch of xml layout files. now, i want to add a functionality where a defined number, i.e. 15, of them will be included in an activity. The 15 layouts should be picked randomly every time the activity is started. How do I do that? I was thinking about an array but could not find any good reference about how to include xml files in an array (random).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

layout references are ints. you can simply choose one using :

```
int[] layouts = new int[] {R.layout.one, R.layout.two, R.layout.three ...};

setContentView(layouts[new Random().nextInt(layouts.length)]);
```

Comment: -1: Right now you give 0, 1, 2 as possible ints. This isn't necessarily equivalent to the layout ids. You will want to have `setContentView(layouts[new Random().nextInt(layout.length)]);`

Comment: i already tried a way similar to your suggestion and it works for showing randomly any of all my layouts. but how do i "dynamically(?)"  define which of my 100 layouts make it to the array as a random selection (only 15 for instance)?

Comment: @jay: If you pack them with the resources, they aren't dynamic. Just type them out. If you load the from somewhere else it get's more complicated. But if you got 100 layouts, I'd think of an easier way to use them. Possible think about building them in code, if there are only minor differences...

Comment: @StackOverflowException : right, i missed that part, that's a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @jay: You would use a `Set<Integer> availableLayouts` at start and genereate a `Set<Integer> chosenLayouts`. Everytime you put one id into `chosenLayouts`, you'd remove it from `availableLayouts` to avoid duplicates. The generation of chosenLayouts works just like described in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You could override Application.onCreate or in your main Activity.onCreate() and set the resource id of your desired layout in a SharedPreference.

```
public static final String LAYOUT_ID = "random.layout.id";
private static int[] LAYOUTS = new int[] { R.layout.default, R.layout.fancy };

public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putInt(LAYOUT_ID, getRandomLayoutId()).commit();
}

private int getRandomLayoutId() {
    Random r = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    return LAYOUTS[r.nextInt(LAYOUTS.length)];
}
```

This id can then be used somewhere in your app with setContentView().

```
private static final int DEFAULT_ID = R.layout.default;

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
setContentView(getInt(MyApplication.LAYOUT_ID, DEFAULT_ID));
```

If you do it in your main Activity it may apply a new layout even on orientation changes or similar events.